# CSS: div overlay that fits its td and stays on top of the td's content

Tags: css, html-table, overlay

I would like to have divs that overlay their td container while filling them completely (width and height). They should also be on top of the td content (above its text)

The problem is that the table is responsive and thus, the td's have variable widths.

**One important thing**: the number of columns is unknown and can be changed by the user in real time. So I can't use 'calc( (100% /x) - 1px )'...

How can I achieve that?

Here's the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4vq8ao6r/4/

The attempt is using an absolute positioned div but I tried many things with no satisfying result.
I can achieve this with jQuery but it's resource heavy (especially on resize) and I would like to just use css if possible.

html:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
          <th>Col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Row1</td>
          <td>
              Data1
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data2
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data3
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data4
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Row2</td>
          <td>
              Data1
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data2
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data3
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
              Data4
              <div class="overlay"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    pointer-events: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#212933;
    color:#e5ebea;
    font-family:'lato';
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:11px;
    user-select:none;
  text-align:center;
}

table{
    display:table;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed; 
    user-select:none;
    width:100%;
}

tr{
    display:table-row;
}

th {
    display:table-cell;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:19px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background:#2e3844;
    border:1px solid #56647c;
    overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
}

th:first-child{
    background:#212933;
}

td {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:6px;
    border:1px solid #56647c;
    overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
}
td:first-child{
    background:#28303a;
}

.overlay{
  background:red;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/za8qmLy0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Basically - make the td position: relative; and then your abs positioned overlay can have top/right/bottom/left all set to 0

```
html,body{
    pointer-events: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#212933;
    color:#e5ebea;
    font-family:'lato';
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:11px;
    user-select:none;
  text-align:center;
}

table{
    display:table;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed; 
    user-select:none;
    width:100%;
}

tr{
    display:table-row;
}

th {
    display:table-cell;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:19px;
    padding-left:10px;
    background:#2e3844;
    border:1px solid #56647c;
    overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
}

th:first-child{
    background:#212933;
}

td {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:6px;
    border:1px solid #56647c;
    overflow:hidden;
  height:40px;
  position: relative;
}
td:first-child{
    background:#28303a;
}

.overlay{
  background:red;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chmxnvzb/ ?

Comment: Darn!  You beat me to the punch.  Take the widths and heights out of `.overlay` and you got it.

Comment: Benlumley: thank you very much!
@Pete: of course it doesn't represent that as it is what I'm trying to achieve. I gave a width to the divs so that we can see them or they won't appear at all and it might confuse the reader. That was a visual choice I made. 
Thank you all!

Comment: @Daniel: no, without the width and height it wasn't working neither. What made the difference was to add a position relative to the td as Benlumney suggested and THEN get rid of the width and height made a difference. Thank you!

Comment: To all of you: you are totally right, it is a duplicate. I made my research before posting but the keywords I used didn't lead me to the right place. Thank you all!